# AC/DC converter with multi ports

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I want to reproduce the following circuit:

[image]

My question is about how I make the AC/DC converter with 3 and 2 input and output ports, respectively?

My code and respective output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]

\draw (0,0) to[short,-o](0,0.75);
\draw [very thick] (0,0.78)--(80:1.2);
\draw (0,1.25) to[short,o-] (0,2) to (1,2)
to [L](1,0) to (0,0);
\draw (0,2) to (-1.5,2) to (-1.5, 1.25) to (-2, 1.25);
\draw (0,0) to (-1.5,0) to (-1.5, 0.75) to (-2, 0.75);
\draw (-4,1) to [sacdc] (-3,1);
\draw[dashed] (-1.75,-0.5) rectangle ++(4,2.75);
\node[font=\sffamily] at (1.25,-0.25) {Cryogenic Region};
\node[font=\sffamily] at (1.6,1) {SC Coil};
\node[font=\sffamily] at (-0.75,1) {SC Switch};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *very* brute-force solution (you can do things more elegantly with `calc` and with relative positioning), but... (see comments in code).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]

\draw (0,0) to[short,-o](0,0.75);
\draw [very thick] (0,0.78)--(80:1.2);
\draw (0,1.25) to[short,o-] (0,2) to (1,2)
to [L](1,0) to (0,0);
\draw (0,2) to (-1.5,2) to (-1.5, 1.25) to (-2, 1.25);
\draw (0,0) to (-1.5,0) to (-1.5, 0.75) to (-2, 0.75);
% use the node-form, align at the east side with the two wires above
\node [sacdcshape, anchor=east](ACDC) at (-2,1) {};
% draw the input wires
\draw (ACDC.west) -- ++(-1,0);
\draw ([yshift=0.2cm]ACDC.west) -- ++(-1,0);
\draw ([yshift=-0.2cm]ACDC.west) -- ++(-1,0);
%
\draw[dashed] (-1.75,-0.5) rectangle ++(4,2.75);
\node[font=\sffamily] at (1.25,-0.25) {Cryogenic Region};
\node[font=\sffamily] at (1.6,1) {SC Coil};
\node[font=\sffamily] at (-0.75,1) {SC Switch};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you can use the `cute switch` to draw the switch, no need to make it by hand. And if you like the original drawing of the AD-DC converter, this is double too, on the spot to using subcircuitis.